# HitCounter in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to build a hit counter for different parts of the website in ASP.NET MVC - any idea where the best place to do this would be, or a good way to do it? We're wanting to track how many hits individual parts of the website get.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Depending on the granularity you want, here are some options:

- You can implement an [ActionFilterAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actionfilterattribute.aspx) that records the hit to some store.
- You can derive from [DefaultControllerFactory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.defaultcontrollerfactory.aspx) and record the hit for each requested Controller.

Answer (score 5):

If you are looking for website stats, I would use [Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/).