# Hit counter for MVC ASP.NET website

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

How to create a hit counter(visitor counter) for each page in MVC website?
And store information in MS SQL Database. The same as stackoverflow using on each page.

Please show me an example. Thank u

Comment: Sorry but I voted to close. This is just too vague. You want a visitor counter, but you haven't specified much of it's function. Where do you want to store data? In a database? A file? Do you want it to read access logs for visitor data? Plus it is basically "show me the codez".

Comment: possible duplicate of [HitCounter in MVC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2086525/hitcounter-in-mvc)

Comment: Ok, and finally as always question not answered. The examples you mentioned don't have explanation how to implement hit counter and very superficial. What is the point to comment question and not to give proper answer? Finally stackoverflow has a lot of question without answers just a lot of stupid comments.

Comment: As always the quality of the answer depends on the quality of the question..

Comment: @Andrew Fales: Yeah but when I posted my comment your question had basically no information what so ever which could give a specific enough answer. And @Daniel Elliott gave you a link to another question which may contain answers. If you want somebody to do it all for you this is not the place.

Comment: Jeez.  When you execute a controller, increment a field in the database.  Set a property PageCount in a base model (from which all other models extend) or stick it in the ViewData dictionary.  Its as close to trivial as possible.

Comment: Why not use Google Analytics for this purpose?

Answer (score 1):

In your master page insert a function call that logs the name of the page or whatever other details you want.  Run your counts and there you go.

Comment: Be careful to check the User Agent ID in your function to make sure that you are not counting robots as well :)

Answer (score 1):

I was able to do this using Session variables, sql server db in ASP.NET MVC.

Note: I used session variables instead of storing client IP address. As saving all the client address will overflow your database. This works similar to the Stackoverflow pages viewed property showing for every question at the top right.

This is how it worked for me.

Whenever a user opens a particular web page in your website, the counter increments and the updated count will be updated in sql server database(it could be anyother database) tables.
If the same user visits the same webpage again within the same session, the counter will not be incrmented. That means if user refreshes a web page multiple times with in the same session, the counter will not be incremented, as it is a single visit by that user.
If the same visitor closes his session(say he closes the browser) and reopens the same web page the counter will be incremented considering it as a separate visit.
Here are the steps I followed to implement it.

Have a method which will be automatically called before every Action method.
Inside this method, initiate a session if it is not done already and check if the user has visited this page already.
Now, update the counter variable accordingly and save the count to db if required.
Here is the complete procedure I have followed. Hope it helps.

Source: [Count number of visitors of a page in asp.net mvc (HIT counter)](http://www.logicalfeed.com/posts/1135/Count-number-of-visitors-of-a-page-in-asp-net-mvc-HIT-counter)